# Store the return of a select in multiple variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure how to ask this. I'm getting information in a stored procedure by running a `select` and saving the results into a variable, but is there a way to reduce this, all of this is inside a stored procedure.

```
SET @VAR1 = (SELECT PAR1 FROM TABLE1)
SET @VAR2 = (SELECT PAR2 FROM TABLE1)
SET @VAR3 = (SELECT PAR3 FROM TABLE1)
```

but could I get it instead some other way?

Like:

```
SET @VAR1, @VAR2, @VAR3 = (SELECT PAR1, PAR2, PART3 FROM TABLE1)
```

Comment: [SELECT @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```sql
SELECT
    @VAR1 = PAR1, 
    @VAR2 = PAR2,
    @VAR3 = PAR3
FROM 
    TABLE1
```

And you can see more in the official docs: [SELECT @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)